# "encrypted_asset_image 0.0.1+2" Can't decrypt images in new projects

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

when I open the example in the encrypted asset image library, I can encrypt and decrypt images without any errors.
But when I use the library in new project I can't decrypt or display encrypted images.
(after compile and run the app I can still encrypt and decrypt the images but once I restart or reload the app again It won't decrypt any of the previously encrypted images, I don't face the same problem with the example project)
[image: load image with example project]
[image: load same image with new project same code]

I tried to use different sdk versions but the problem still exists. Any Ideas how to make it work?

The code to encrypt the image:

```
await fileCryptor.encrypt(inputFile: 'assets/Question-1.png', outputFile: 'assets/Question-1-encrypted.png');
```

The code to decrypt the image:

```
await fileCryptor.decrypt(inputFile: 'assets/Question-1-encrypted.png', outputFile: 'assets/Question-1-decrypted.png');
```

The code to display the image:

```
EncryptedAssetImage(assetPath: 'assets/Question-1-encrypted.png', fileCryptor: fileCryptor)
```

Main File (when I run this file in new project it doesn't work. But when I run it in the old example project that provided with the package repository it work fine):

```
import 'package:encrypted_asset_image/encrypted_asset_image.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  late final FileCryptor fileCryptor;

  @override
  void initState() {
    fileCryptor = FileCryptor(key: 'VihW5CNfR9Fmhgz6b5AbUDQPsAzRWCA8', iv: 16, dir: '');
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Encrypted Asset Image Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Container(
                height: 600,
                width: 600,
                color: Colors.black,
                child: EncryptedAssetImage(assetPath: 'assets/Question-1-encrypted.png', fileCryptor: fileCryptor)),
          ],
        ),
        floatingActionButton: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
          children: [
            const SizedBox(width: 20),
            FloatingActionButton(
              onPressed: () async {
                await fileCryptor.encrypt(
                    inputFile: 'assets/Question-1.png', outputFile: 'assets/Question-1-encrypted.png');
              },
              tooltip: 'Encrypt',
              child: const Icon(Icons.enhanced_encryption),
            ),
            const SizedBox(width: 20),
            FloatingActionButton(
              onPressed: () async {
                await fileCryptor.decrypt(
                    inputFile: 'assets/Question-1-encrypted.png', outputFile: 'assets/Question-1-decrypted.png');
              },
              tooltip: 'Decrypt',
              child: const Icon(Icons.no_encryption),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.